# What happened to org-vm.el?

Tags: hyperlink, org-mode

When did "org-vm.el" get replaced by "ol-vm.el"?  These have the purpose of creating and using a link to mail in a View Mail (vm) folder.  Such a link is in a file that is using Org-mode.

Answer (score 0):

From the git log for the file, link related files were renamed `ol-*.el` in early March 2019.